# Insert into sqlite3 a null date from pyramid framework using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, date, sqlalchemy, pyramid

```
python 2.7
pyramid 1.3a4
sqlalchemy 7.3
sqlite3.7.9
```

from sqlite prompt > I can do:

```
insert into risk(travel_dt) values ('')
also
insert into risk(travel_dt) values(Null)
```

Both result in a new row with a null value for `risk.travel_dt` but when I try those `travel_dt` values from pyramid, Sqlalchemy gives me an error.

In the first case, I get `sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError`:

> SQLite Date type only accepts python date objects as input

In the second case, I get `Null is not defined`. When I use "Null", I get the first case error

I apologize for another question on nulls: I have read a lot of material but must have missed something simple. Thanks for any help
Clemens Herschel

Answer (score 1):

While you didn't provide any insight into the table definition you're using or any example code, I am guessing the issue is due to confusing `NULL` (the database reserved word) and `None` (the Python reserved word).

The error message is telling you that you need to call your SQLA methods with valid python `date` objects, rather than strings such as "Null" or ''.

Assuming you have a Table called `risk` containing a Column called `travel_dt`, you should be able to create a row in that table with something sort of like:

```
risk.insert().values(travel_dt=None)
```

Note that this is just a snippet, you would need to execute such a call within an `engine` context like that defined in the [SA Docs SQL Expression Language Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/tutorial.html#executing).

Comment: That worked. Sorry I did not provide an example code or table definition; I was trying to be succinct. Good inferences. Thanks for your help; that was my confusion.